# SQLite Expert database open in command prompt

Tags: sqlite

How does one open a SQLite Expert database by using command prompt in windows XP? My database file extension is s3db and SQLite Expert exe file name is SQLiteExpertPers.exe.

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as an SQLite Expert database. Your program is called "SQLite Expert", but the database is just SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a shell. (Start | Run, type `cmd`, and push the "Ok" button.)

Change to the drive and directory your SQLite database is in. If your database is in "My Documents", you'd type

```
cd "\Documents and Settings\YourLoginName\My Documents"
```

and hit the [Enter] key.

If you're joined to a Windows domain, you'd type

```
cd "\Documents and Settings\YourLoginName.YOURDOMAIN\My Documents"
```

Then run SQLite3, and give it the name of your database.

```
sqlite3 YourDatabase.s3db
```

The error message

> 'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

means sqlite3 is not in your path. Either provide the full path to sqlite3.exe

```
"c:\Program Files\SQLite\sqlite3.exe YourDatabase.s3db"
```

or change the path setting (Control panel, System, "Advanced" tab, "Environment Variables" button).

Once you're in, type `.tables` at the sqlite prompt to make sure you're in the right database.

Comment: Thank You brother. It is work fine now. Actually sqlite3.exe file was not created in my SQLiteExpertPers.exe setup location. Now with sqlite3.exe file I can run it in command prompt. Thank you very much.